# Why this OR operator not working in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use Binary OR operator in perl to get some information from a file. I used this regular expression

```
 /(fix|issue)\s*#/mi
```

but it does not find any match. 
in the file there are 4 matches for 'fix #' and 3 match for 'issue #', and I got that right when using them separately without OR operator.

```
   /fix\s*#/mi

   /issue\s*#/mi
```

So the OR suppose to return 7 matches, but it return nothing.

These two lines are exactly in the file

```
Add test for the example in issue #142.

 Fix #1190
```

Am I doing that correct?

Thanks for help

Comment: That's not binary OR, it's an OR in a regular expression. Without seeing your real input, we don't know if your pattern works. Without `/g` you will never get more than one match unless there are zero.

Comment: The input is big file with more than 1000 line. The file has exactly "issue #" and "fix #".

Comment: The size of the file doesn't really matter to us. You can include one line that you think should match, and one that shouldn't. Better yet, [edit] your question and include the full program you've written. As choroba below points out, this should work. So the bug is probably in the code we don't see.

Comment: I copy paste two lines form the file. Thank you for that.

Comment: So we are building a git log parser to auto-close tickets or identify mentioned tickets. That's info you could have given us.

Comment: I did not really understand your comment . But yes the file has part of git log, and I want to know how many issue and fix in it. 
Is that different from normal string file?

Comment: There is no difference, but it helps to give context. Now please show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. It matches once per line as the `/g` wasn't given. Also, `/m` is useless as neither `^` nor `$` are used. `/i` makes `ISSUE #` match, too.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

while (<DATA>) {
    say "Matched $1" if /(fix|issue)\s*#/mi;
}

__DATA__
fix #
fix # fix #
---
issue #
issue # issue #
```

Note that "binary or" is a different operator used outside of regular expressions:

```
say 4 | 8;  # 12
```

`|` in a regex is called "alternation".

Comment: Sorry, I mixed between them i meant the OR in regular expression. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Hukh: you've accepted an answer which basically says that your original code should have worked. It might be helpful to anyone having similar problems in the future, if you were to explain why your code didn't work.